# Will JAX-RS/Jersey resource paths honor inheritance?

Tags: java, url, jersey, jax-rs

Say I want the following URLs exposed by my JAX-RS/Jersey app:

```
http://myapp.example.com/app/fizz
http://myapp.example.com/app/buzz
http://myapp.example.com/app/foo
http://myapp.example.com/app/bar
```

Say I want `/app` to be a parent base resource, and `/app/*` to be "child" resources. Will the following accomplish the URL strategy I'm looking for (?):

```
@Path('/app')
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public abstract class AppResource {
    // Whatever...
}

@Path('/fizz') // <--- right here, will FizzResource live at /app/fizz?
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class FizzResource extends AppResource {
    // Whatever...
}
```

**Will the `FizzResource` be exposed at `/app/fizz` or just `/fizz`?**

Comment: What do you want `FizzResource` to gain from `AppResource` besides the `@Path`? I think that is the important question. If it's just want the path, just add it in the configuration and forget the abstract class. If you want some resource methods _and_ the path, the `@Path` value will not be inherited, so just put it in the configuration, but still extend from the base class.

Comment: @DonCruickshank, nope, but Cassio answered it for me ;-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Will the `FizzResource` be exposed at `/app/fizz` or just `/fizz`?

### Short answer

`FizzResource` will be exposed at `/fizz`.

### Long answer

Quoting the [JSR 339](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=339) (section *3.6* about *Annotation Inheritance*):

> If a subclass or implementation method has **any** JAX-RS annotations then
>   **all** of the annotations on the superclass or interface method are
>   ignored.

The [specification](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=339) also says:

> For consistency with other Java EE specifications, it is recommended to **always repeat annotations instead of relying on annotation inheritance**.

### Creating sub-resources

The [JAX-RS/Jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2464) explains how to create sub-resources:

> [`@Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) may be used on classes and such classes are referred to as root resource classes.
>
> [`@Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) may also be used on methods of root resource classes. This enables common functionality for a number of resources to be grouped together and potentially reused.
>
> The first way [`@Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) may be used is on resource methods and such methods are referred to as **sub-resource methods**.

So, do the following to create sub-resources:

```
@Path("/app")
public class YourHandler {

    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String yourHandlerForApp() {
        // This method is be exposed at /app
    }

    @Path("/fizz") 
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String yourHandlerForAppSlashFizz() {
        // This method is be exposed at /app/fizz
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the answers given are the best for the original problem statement.

He wants to have his subresources in separate classes.  That's understandable and admirable because to not do that would mean putting all his endpoints in the same class, which would be huge.

If all endpoints on this port start with `/app` then I think the best way to do that is to configure your filter to put it in your `@ApplicationPath`.

If it's not the case that all endpoints start with the same prefix, then you will have to use this style of JAX-RS subresources where you specify a `@Path` but not an HTTP method annotation (`@GET`, etc.) and return an instance of the resource you want to delegate to:

```
@Path("/app")
public class AppResource {
    @Context UriInfo uriInfo;

    @Path("fizz")
    public FizzResource getItemContentResource() {
        return new FizzResource ();
    }
}

@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class FizzResource extends AppResource {
    // Whatever...
}
```

This method of doing resources is provided in the [JAX-RS documentation](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2542).

You can also have all your subresources declare their Paths as

```
    @Path(BASE_URL + "/fizz")
```

Where `BASE_URL` is a static string, but I would try to avoid that because the use of a not-exactly constant parameter to `@Path` seems to cause every JAX-RS IDE plugin I've seen problems.    They aren't able to compute the actual path, so they give up.    So you might lose the ability to have a "JAX-RS View" that allows you to visualize/navigate your JAX-RS resources by the Paths.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is

```
@Path("/app")
public class YourHandler {
   @Path('/')
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public String yourHandlerForApp() {
      // Whatever...
   }

   @Path('/fizz') // <--- right here, will FizzResource live at /app/fizz?
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public String yourHandlerForAppSlashFizz() {
       // Whatever...
   }
}
```